# jQuery function running when not supposed to be

Tags: jquery, function, resize

I have a function that is supposed to run on `$(document).ready` and `$(window).resize`.  It's set not to load when the page's width > 767px.  However when the page is resized to be less than 767px or starts at 767px or less and then is resized to be greater than 767px the class `active-hover` is still being applied on hover for some reason.  Any ideas why?

```
function portfolioResizeHover() {
  var screenWidth = $(document).width();

  if (screenWidth <= 767) {
    $('.portfolio-display-box').hover(function () {
      // remove Class if there is an element with class already applied
      $('.active-hover').removeClass('active-hover');
      // Apply your class to this
      $(this).addClass('active-hover');
    });
  } else {
    $('.portfolio-display-box').removeClass('active-hover');
  }
}
$(document).ready(portfolioResizeHover);
$(window).resize(portfolioResizeHover);
```

Comment: Just follow the instructions: On DOMReady/Resize the browser runs `portfolioResizeHover()`. The function checks the width. If <= 767 then it adds a `mouseenter` (=hover) event handler(!) which adds the class `active-hover` if you move the mouse onto a `.portfolio-display-box` element. If the width changes to a value > 767 you remove the class `active-hover` - but not the event handler(!) ;)

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix it by adding `$('.portfolio-display-box').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');` to the else statement, removing the event handler.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `resize` event is called multiple times when a window changes its size. This means that your function will add multiple `hover` event handlers!